# MS Access 2013 - counting number of dates

Tags: vba, ms-access, report, calculated-field

I'm trying to count the number of occurrences of a number on a report. This number is a text box with a control source of:

```
number=lastvisit+60-today()
```

This gives a number of days (3, 12, 21, etc....) and I need to count the number of occurrences of these numbers less than 10 (this can change to 8 or 15 or.....). That is "*count how many 7's there are*" or "*count how many 9's there are*."

I made this *count* text box with its control source of a few things, none that worked:

1. `=count(iif(number <7,1,0)`
2. `=sum(iif(number <7,1,1)`

Each time I try it, the value is the number of records in that group. The dates are grouped by week.

I hope the image below helps.

[image: drop box link]

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
=Sum(IIf(number < 7, 1, 0)
```

or, if you like:

```
=Sum(Abs(number < 7))
```

Answer (score 0):

Control source is used to bind to a recordset.  If you are purely doing calculations, no control source is needed.  You can try something similar to this to count your numbers.:

```
private sub CountNumbers

     dim intCount as integer

     intCount = DCOUNT("fldField","tblTable", "fldField" > 10)

     me.txtTextBox.value = intCount

end sub
```

Note: This is untested and will need some tailoring to suite the needs of your application.